# Flipping between a standard and grouped style table via segmented control

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol, uitableview

I'm looking to use a UISegmentedControl to flip between two tables on the same view.  One table (the default when the view is loaded) is grouped.  The second table should be plain (non-grouped).  The tableView is set to Grouped in the xib.

Right now I'm doing a reloadData when flipping between the two sets of data.  So of course both "views" are in the grouped style.  I know I can't change a tableView's style once set, but I'm looking to mimic that intent.

The best idea I've had is to create a second (plain) tableView in code, then flip between the two as needed.  I could either show/hide (keeping them both in memory) or add and remove from the superView.

Both views may result in the user clicking through to additional pushed viewControllers.  I want to retain consistency with the chain, including the ability to popToRootViewController from viewControllers further down the chain (the view in question is two or three steps down from the root).

Before I tear up my code with this idea I figure I'd check around to see what others thought.

Thanks!

UPDATE:  Getting there.  When I want to display the plain table view I have this:

```
PlainViewController *plainViewController = [[PlainViewController alloc] init];
UIView *plainTableView = plainViewController.view;
plainTableView.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:plainViewController.view];
```

which loads and displays fine.  But when PlainViewController's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` fires, it fails to load the next view.  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is firing (it's logged), but `pushViewController` does nothing; the next view's viewDidLoad never fires.

I suspect there's a discontinuity in the NavigationController but not quite sure where to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate `UIViewController` and add its table to the 'main' view.

```
PlainTableViewController *ctr = [[PlainTableViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:ctr.view];
[ctr release];
```

You can also easily animate this process:

```
PlainTableViewController *ctr = [[PlainTableViewController alloc] init];

UIView *plainTableView = ctr.view;
plainTableView.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:plainTableView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
        animations:^{ 
            groupedTableView.frame = CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320, 480);
            plainTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);}
        completion:^(BOOL finished){[groupedTableView removeFromSuperView];}
];

[ctr release];
```

***Notice:** You don't add it as view controller in your navigation controller so all calls of `popToRootViewController` should lead to your 'main' viewController. And that's what you want.*

Answer (score 1):

Assign your `tableViewStyle` in something like `- (void) refreshTable;` then when you tap your  segmentedControl, also call `[myTable reloadData];`

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different views that have table with both the style but with the same data and you can flip that two views on the segment selected index change event

OR

You have to remove the table from its superview and then realloc table with the selected style and add it again to that view.

Answer (score 0):

I think that adding/removing the table views from the view containing the segmented control should work seamlessly.

In order to keep consistency, I think the approach is storing somewhere the information as to which view is selected through the segmented control, so that when you are displaying that view you know which is the current style. This info will be also stored in NSUserDefaults, so that it is persistent across runs.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, every time that the segmented control changes, re-create the UITableView.
Upside: saves you from writing too much code, memory.
Downside: uses a bit more CPU.

But you'd be redrawing the view with reloadData anyway, so it is a very minimal CPU drain to simply recreate the view.

```
-(void)segmentedControlChanged{

CGRect originalFrame = tableView.frame;

UITableViewStyle tableStyle;

if(selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
tableStyle = UITableViewStylePlain;
} else {
tableStyle = UITableViewStyleGrouped;
}

[tableView removeFromSubview];
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:originalFrame style:tableStyle];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];

}
```

Note: code written by memory without checking in Xcode.